# What are the negative consequences for choosing 8 S-boxes for DES vs 1 S-box for AES?

Tags: aes, des, s-boxes

DES has 8 different S-boxes, and AES has only 1.

What are the negative consequences of such choices?

Comment: I'd guess mostly implementation complexity.

Comment: The AES s-box is much larger and non linear than the DES s-boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation complexity in software and constrained hardware.

In Serpent, each round uses the same S-box, even though 8 s-boxes are used. This makes it easier to bitsplice the cipher, or process each 4-bit s-box in parallel.

The minimum gate count for a DES implementation is 2300 gates. For Present it is 1075 gates.

Software and constrained hardware implementations benefit from a cipher that can be easily serialized.

1. [Hash Functions and RFID Tags: Mind the Gap](https://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2008/51540279/51540279.pdf)